# Getting the value of dynamic created radiobuttons

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created array of radio buttons in this way:

```
RadioButton[] radio = new RadioButton[size]; 

for (int i = 0; i < size ; i++)
  {
      radio[i] = new RadioButton();
      radio[i].ID = "voted"+i.ToString();
      radio[i].GroupName = "voted";
      Session[radio[i].ID] = radio[i];
  }
```

and when the user clicks the button the event is

```
protected void Votes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton r=new RadioButton();
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)Session["cancount"]; i++)
    {
         r=(RadioButton)(Session["voted" + i.ToString()]);
         if (r.Checked)
         {
             //Do somethings; 
         }
    }
}
```

but the value of `r.checked` is always `false`, why it's not changed??

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish here. What does session have to do with figuring out if they selected a radio button? Are you trying to keep track of what the user has voted in? Also how are you adding the radio buttons to the page?

Comment: yes I want to keep track what the user voted in,and I'm not posted my hole code, I'm adding these radio buttons to table which I added to page panel

Comment: please add more context - for example, what part of the page lifecycle are you creating the radio buttons? preinit, init, load, prerender? where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is missing lots of context, but given the wholly strange way you appear to be writing your web site, I'd imagine that the problem is that you never added the radio button controls the page's control hierarchy. Also, I'm guessing that you're creating the radio buttons in the Page_Load event instead of the Page_Init event, which is a problem because they will not pick up clicks from postbacks because they are added *after* the click is processed by ASP.NET.

If this doesn't make any sense to you, then you need to read a little more on how ASP.NET works. You can't treat it exactly like a desktop application. Events and their handlers are separated by HTTP posts, leading to sensitivity in how and where you create and initialize controls.

Comment: yes, you are right. I created the radio buttons in the Page_Load event, When I created them in Page_Init event,my code works correctly. thank you very much

Comment: I'm glad it worked out. I was expecting more +1 for psychic reading, but I'll take what I'm given ;)

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of all the session state stuff, the button that's being clicked is passed to the event handler as the 'sender'. To access the radio button that was clicked just cast it as a radio button and there's your object:

```
RadioButton r = (RadioButton)sender;
```

You're also better off use a RadioButtonList instead of the Session variable you're setting. Then just add RadioButtonList on the page and add the buttons in your loop:

```
myRbl.Items.Add(new ListItem("text", i.ToString(), true));
```